# how to import mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql

I have installed MySqldb through .exe(precompiled). Its is stored in site-packages. But now i don't know how to test, that it is accessable or not. And major problem how to import in my application like import MySqldb. Help me i am very new techie in python i just want to work with my existing Mysql. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open your CMD/Console, type `python`, press `Enter`, type `import MySQLdb` and then press `Enter` again.

If no error is shown, you're ok!